# about sending SMS by writing program

Tags: api, sms

Exccuse me,

may I ask is there any API for sending SMS mesaages to mobile phone through programming?

If there is any, may I ask if there is any recommended one which is morer reliable and have more reasonable prices?

Comment: You could perhaps start by browsing the SMS tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sms

Answer (score 3):

Using SMPP is overkill unless you are planning to send smses at the speed of 50 a second or more.

For incidental sending of SMSes you can use HTTP calls to a SMS gateway. The Call will be similar to:

http://www.somesmsgateway.com/api.php?to=31612345678&msg=helloworld&username=yourusername&password=yourpassword

an example of such a gateway is [clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com)

Comment: There are a *lot* of gateways with many and various APIs - make sure you look at costs and try and find independent assessments of reliability.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [Smpp OpenSource](http://opensmpp.logica.com/introhtml/menu.htm)

> SUMMARY:
>
> SMPP stands for Short Message Peer to
>   Peer. It is a communication protocol
>   designed for transfer of short
>   messages between short message centre
>   and SMS application.

Answer (score 0):

[Zeep Mobile](http://www.zeepmobile.com/) or use an [Aggregator](http://www.openmarket.com)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of SMS providers. You should [take a look at PW](http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/sms),

Nexmo, Twilio, Hoiio, Zeepmobile, etc comes to mind.